# How to get access to an active Page in Silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, silverlight, navigation

Quick question.. I'm trying to access a UI control, on a specific Page that is loaded on startup, by using JavaScript.

My MainPage uses a Frame to show a specific Page. From App.xaml.cs I'd like to access an UI control on this specific Page.

Accessing the MainPage is do-able:

```
MainPage m = (MainPage)Application.Current.RootVisual;
m.testField.Text = "Working!";
```

But how can I access the Page that is loaded into the Frame on the MainPage.xaml.cs?

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps..

```
MainPage page = Application.Current.RootVisual as MainPage;
LoadedPage myPage = page.frame.Content as LoadedPage;
```